# How to prove the following result in Analysis?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Suppose that 
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le |\sin x-\sin y| \quad \forall x,y  \in (0,1)$$

Does 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$$ 
exist or not?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does exist.

Since the Sine function is uniformly continuous, we have that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta$ such that if $|x-y|\leq \delta$, then $|\sin x-\sin y|\leq \epsilon$.

Now pick a sequence $x_n\in (0,1)$ converging to zero. Pick $N$ such that if $n>N$, $x_n\leq \frac{\delta}{2}$. Then, for any $m,n\geq N$, $$|x_m-x_n|\leq|x_m|+|x_n|\leq \frac{\delta}{2}+\frac{\delta}{2}=\delta.$$  Consequently $$|f(x_m)-f(x_n)|\leq |\sin x-\sin y|\leq \epsilon.$$

We have shown that $f(x_n)$ is a cauchy sequence for ANY $x_n\to 0$, hence it is convergent since we are dealing with the real numbers.

Finally, the limits of $f(x_n)$ all need to be the same for any such sequence $x_n\to 0$ because if say $f(x_n)\to L_1$ and $f(y_n)\to L_2$ and $L_1\neq L_2$, then we can make up a new sequence $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2\cdots$ converging to zero yet the sequence $f(x_1),f(y_1),f(x_2),f(y_2)\cdots$ not having a limit (since it has two subsequences with different limits), contradicting the previous paragraph.

So the limit you want exists.